# How to add a webview to play a youtube video on it after drawing a rectangle by template matching using openCV in Java android

Tags: java, android, opencv, template-matching

I am Working on an App where I have to do template matching using openCv library.
I have done that and drawn a rectangle on the matched template.
Now I want to use a webview exactly on the rectangle to play some video.
For that I am adding the webview programatically on a FrameLayout.
But I am unable to adjust the positions and the dimensions of the webview on the mobile screen such that it would be placed on the rectangle.I am sharing my code snippet

```
 // Load the source image from a resource
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.full_new);///// source from drawable
        Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

        // Convert the Bitmap to a Mat object
        Mat src = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1, src);

        // Load the template image from a resource
        Drawable drawable2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgg);////// template from drawable
        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable2).getBitmap();

        // Convert the Bitmap to a Mat object
        Mat template = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap2, template);

        // Check that the Mats are not empty
        if (src.empty()) {
            Log.e("TAGGGGGGG", "Failed to load src image!");
            return;
        }

        if (template.empty()) {
            Log.e("TAGGGGGGG", "Failed to load template image!");
            return;
        }

        // Convert images to grayscale
        Mat sourceImageGray = new Mat();
        Mat templateImageGray = new Mat();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(src, sourceImageGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(template, templateImageGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(sourceImageGray, sourceImageGray, new Size(3, 3), 0);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(templateImageGray, templateImageGray, new Size(3, 3), 0);

        // Check that the grayscale conversion worked
        if (sourceImageGray.empty()) {
            Log.e("TAGGGGGGG", "Failed to convert src image to grayscale!");
            return;
        }

        if (templateImageGray.empty()) {
            Log.e("TAGGGGGGG", "Failed to convert template image to grayscale!");
            return;
        }



        // Create a Mat object to hold the matching scores
        Mat result = new Mat(src.rows() - template.rows() + 1, src.cols() - template.cols() + 1, CvType.CV_8UC1);

        // Perform the template matching
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(sourceImageGray, templateImageGray, result, Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);///////////

        // Find the best match
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
        Point maxLoc = mmr.maxLoc;

        // Draw the rectangle on the image
        int w = template.cols();
        int h = template.rows();
        Point rectPoint1 = maxLoc;
        Point rectPoint2 = new Point(maxLoc.x + w, maxLoc.y + h);
        Scalar color = new Scalar(255, 255, 0);
        int thickness = 10;
        Imgproc.rectangle(src, rectPoint1, rectPoint2, color, thickness);

        // Apply Canny edge detection on the rectangle region
        Mat rectMat = src.submat((int) rectPoint1.y, (int) rectPoint2.y, (int) rectPoint1.x, (int) rectPoint2.x);

        int webViewWidth = template.width();
        int webViewHeight = template.height();
        int webViewX = (int) (maxLoc.x + (template.cols() / 2) - (webViewWidth / 2));
        int webViewY = (int) (maxLoc.y + (template.rows() / 2) - (webViewHeight / 2));

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        // Create a WebView and add it to a FrameLayout
        WebView webView = new WebView(this);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame);
        frameLayout.addView(webView);


        frameLayout.setX((float) rectPoint1.x);//98
        frameLayout.setY((float) rectPoint1.y);//182
        frameLayout.getLayoutParams().width =  (int)(rectPoint2.x - rectPoint1.x);;
        frameLayout.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (rectPoint2.y - rectPoint1.y);;

        webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("http://www.youtube.com") || url.startsWith("vnd.youtube")) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        String embedUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + "uJIfpoRM-3U";
        webView.loadUrl(embedUrl);

        // Convert the result Mat to a Bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.cols(), src.rows(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Utils.matToBitmap(src, bitmap);

        // Set the Bitmap to an ImageView
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

I have done that and drawn a rectangle on the matched template.
Now I want to use a webview exactly on the rectangle to play some video.
For that I am adding the webview programatically on a FrameLayout.
But I am unable to adjust the positions and the dimensions of the webview on the mobile screen such that it would be placed on the rectangle

Comment: what exactly is the problem? how to position a widget?

Comment: yes need to place any widget in my case webview exactly on the rectangle drawn after template matching.The position and size should vary according to the rectangle size and position on the screen.